# Pinta installs but won't load

Tags: pinta

Pinta paint program installs from Software Center, but doesn't load from launcher icon, or load from applications folder icon, or Terminal.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on an Intel Atom dual core machine with 2 gigs of RAM and Nvidia Ion graphics, using the Nvidia driver.

Output of `pinta`:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: 'gtk-close' is not a valid resource name of assembly 'Pinta.Resources, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader.InitFromAssemblyResource (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gdk.Pixbuf..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gdk.Pixbuf.LoadFromResource (System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetIcon (System.String name, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.ResourceManager.GetIcon (System.String name, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.ResourceManager.GetIcon (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.Gui.Widgets.OpenImagesListWidget..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.OpenImagesPad.Initialize (MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockFrame workspace, Gtk.Menu padMenu) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow.CreateDockAndPads (Gtk.HBox container) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow.CreatePanels (Pinta.WindowShell shell) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow.CreateWindow () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: 'gtk-close' is not a valid resource name of assembly 'Pinta.Resources, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader.InitFromAssemblyResource (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gdk.Pixbuf..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gdk.Pixbuf.LoadFromResource (System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetIcon (System.String name, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.ResourceManager.GetIcon (System.String name, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.ResourceManager.GetIcon (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.Gui.Widgets.OpenImagesListWidget..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.OpenImagesPad.Initialize (MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockFrame workspace, Gtk.Menu padMenu) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow.CreateDockAndPads (Gtk.HBox container) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow.CreatePanels (Pinta.WindowShell shell) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow.CreateWindow () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by installing `gnome-icon-theme-full`.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full
```